# Strange behavior of WinAPI's SendInput? Alternative?

Tags: c#, c, user-interface, winapi, automation

is there any alernative way how to post sequence of strokes on keyboard?

With SendInput code below works very well and confidently on my computer, but while I testing it on others (with same or other operating system (W7/W10)) it does not.
When I tried to check return code and last error, I received success everywhere (posted X keystrokes, return code: 0), but no strokes have been done.

My program is almost done, earlier someone suggest me to use UIAutomation, but I'm not familiar with the technology at the moment and I guess is nonsense to fully re-do whole part of code.

Can anyone tell me about winapi, or C# class, which is alternative to SendInput and do its job reliably, or WHAT is bad in my code, while on my machine works well and on others not.

Thanks a lot

```
PIXEL_COLOR pix = PIXEL_COLOR.PIX_UNKNOWN;
        bool isException = false;
        string mess ="";
        uint a = 0, b = 0;
        int ea = -1, eb = -1;

        try
        {
            const int TRUE = 1;
            const int FALSE = 0;
            MainWindow.ShowWindow(GetParent(clickSettings.GetHandler), SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            SetWindowPos(GetParent(clickSettings.GetHandler), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);


            switch (lev.expiry)
            {
                case 5:
                case 10:
                case 15:
                    PutSingleClick(clickSettings.GetHandler, clickSettings.GetM15.GetX, clickSettings.GetM15.GetY);
                    break;
                case 60:
                    PutSingleClick(clickSettings.GetHandler, clickSettings.GetM60.GetX, clickSettings.GetM60.GetY);
                    break;
            }
            //show list
            PutSingleClick(clickSettings.GetHandler, clickSettings.GetInstruments.GetX, clickSettings.GetInstruments.GetY);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //downarrows
            a = PutKeystroke(hWndMain, (int)lev.symbol, TRUE, out ea);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

There is two mouse click, which second is on browser's combobox where I need to "manually" (by keyboard) choose one item. It doing native winapi function from library with this code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall PutKeystroke(HWND hnd, int index, BOOL isDown, int& err)
{
    INPUT ip = {0};
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wVk =isDown? VK_DOWN : VK_UP;
    int times;
    if(index < 2)
        times = index+1;
    else
        times = index+2; //only correction, I forgot an option on third position which is not needed (and I'm very lazy :)
    INPUT ips[100] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < times*2; i+=2)
    {
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        ips[i] = ip;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        ips[i+1] = ip;
    }
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    ips[times*2] = ip;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ips[(times*2)+1] = ip;

    UINT s = SendInput((times*2)+2, &ips[0], sizeof(INPUT));
    err = GetLastError();
    return s;
}
```

After this work I have more to do, clicks, write some numbers to text box, etc, after that I have to return combox option to default by this:

```
//combobox show
PutSingleClick(clickSettings.GetHandler, clickSettings.GetInstruments.GetX, clickSettings.GetInstruments.GetY);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
//uparrows
b = PutKeystroke(hWndMain, (int)lev.symbol + 15, FALSE, out eb);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

and if all ok (no exception happens, unlock the topmost browser and see the results:

```
        finally
        {
            SetWindowPos(GetParent(clickSettings.GetHandler), HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            ShowWindow(GetParent(clickSettings.GetHandler), SW_HIDE);
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Keystrokes: choosing {0} error {1}, return to all {2} error {3}", a, ea, b, eb));
            if (isException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception: {0} ", mess));
            }
            else
            {

                if (pix == PIXEL_COLOR.PIX_GREEN)
                { .........
```

Where I have **allways** positive results (Keystrokes: choosing X, error 0, returning Y, error 0), but combo is drawns, but **no** strokes done.

Whats wrong?

Thanks a lot

**Minimal, complete and verifiable example below**
Primarily is program designed for automated using a web aplication for HighLow broker at www.highlow.net . You need to click to "open a demo" (it free and no reg needed), there will be on right side some combobox, which is object of problems.

****C# console app code ****

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;

namespace clickTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum SYMBOLS
        {
            AUDJPY, AUDNZD, CADJPY, CHFJPY, EURAUD, EURGBP,
            EURJPY, EURUSD, GBPAUD, GBPJPY, GBPUSD, NZDJPY,
            NZDUSD, USDCAD, USDCHF, USDJPY, GOLD, UNKNOWN
        };

        const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;


        [DllImport(@"tradeInterop.dll")]
        public static extern void PutSingleClick(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y);
        [DllImport(@"tradeInterop.dll")]
        public static extern uint PutKeystroke(IntPtr shouldBeNULL, int times, int isDown, out int err);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr precendingHwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint flags);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
        public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int cmdShow);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hwnd);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UInt32 handler = 0;
            int x, y = 0;
            int keystrokesCount = 0;
            IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
            IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
            UInt32 originalHandler = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("H WND (hexadecimal) 0 = exit: ");
                handler = UInt32.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (handler == 0)
                {
                    ShowBrowser((IntPtr)originalHandler, IntPtr.Zero);
                    break;
                }
                originalHandler = handler;
                HideBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_BOTTOM);
                Console.WriteLine("X: ");
                x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Y: ");
                y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Choose instrument index (e.g. EURUSD=7)");
                keystrokesCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Getting browser maximized and topomost");

                ShowBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_TOPMOST);

                Console.WriteLine("Clicking on combobox");
                PutSingleClick((IntPtr)handler, x, y);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // for content of combo full load
                Console.WriteLine("Putting keystrokes");
                int lastErr = -1;
                uint strokesPut = PutKeystroke(IntPtr.Zero, keystrokesCount, 1, out lastErr); // 1 = TRUE, is key down

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                HideBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_BOTTOM);

                Console.WriteLine("Keys down pressed, {0} would be choosen", (SYMBOLS)keystrokesCount);
                Console.WriteLine("From library: Sent {0} strokes, error: {1}", strokesPut, lastErr);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();

                ShowBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_TOPMOST);
                PutSingleClick((IntPtr)handler, x, y);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                strokesPut = PutKeystroke(IntPtr.Zero, keystrokesCount + 5, 0, out lastErr);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                HideBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_BOTTOM);

                Console.WriteLine("Keys up pressed, ALL would be choosen");
                Console.WriteLine("From library: Sent {0} strokes, error: {1}", strokesPut, lastErr);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void ShowBrowser(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr precHwnd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Showing browser...");
            ShowWindow(GetParent(hwnd), SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            SetWindowPos(GetParent(hwnd), precHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }

        private static void HideBrowser(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr precHwnd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hiding browser...");
            SetWindowPos(GetParent(hwnd), precHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            ShowWindow(GetParent(hwnd), SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
```

**** TradeInterop dll and its relevant functions ****

```
int _stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD fdwReason, PVOID pvReserved)
{
    return true;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PutSingleClick(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, BOOL needFocus = TRUE)
{
    if(needFocus == TRUE)
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0,0));
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(0,0));
    }
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));

}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall PutKeystroke(HWND hnd, int index, BOOL isDown, int& err)
{
    INPUT ip = {0};
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wVk =isDown? VK_DOWN : VK_UP;
    int times;
    if(index < 2)
        times = index+1;
    else
        times = index+2;

    INPUT ips[100] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < times*2; i+=2)
    {
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        ips[i] = ip;

        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        ips[i+1] = ip;
    }

    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    ips[times*2] = ip;

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ips[(times*2)+1] = ip;
    err = -1;
    UINT s = SendInput((times*2)+2, &ips[0], sizeof(INPUT));
    err = GetLastError();
    return s;
}
```

**REMAKED C# part with Davids's idea and suggestion, problem unfortunately persists**

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace clickTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum SYMBOLS
        {
            AUDJPY, AUDNZD, CADJPY, CHFJPY, EURAUD, EURGBP,
            EURJPY, EURUSD, GBPAUD, GBPJPY, GBPUSD, NZDJPY,
            NZDUSD, USDCAD, USDCHF, USDJPY, GOLD, UNKNOWN
        };

        const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;


        [DllImport(@"tradeInterop.dll")]
        public static extern void PutSingleClick(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y);
        /*[DllImport(@"tradeInterop.dll")]
        public static extern uint PutKeystroke(IntPtr shouldBeNULL, int times, int isDown, out int err);*/
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr precendingHwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint flags);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
        public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int cmdShow);
        [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hwnd);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UInt32 handler = 0;
            int x, y = 0;
            int keystrokesCount = 0;
            IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
            IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
            UInt32 originalHandler = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("H WND (hexadecimal) 0 = exit: ");
                handler = UInt32.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (handler == 0)
                {
                    ShowBrowser((IntPtr)originalHandler, IntPtr.Zero);
                    break;
                }
                originalHandler = handler;
                HideBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_BOTTOM);
                Console.WriteLine("X: ");
                x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Y: ");
                y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Choose instrument index (e.g. EURUSD=7)");
                keystrokesCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Getting browser maximized and topomost");

                ShowBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_TOPMOST);

                Console.WriteLine("Clicking on combobox");
                PutSingleClick((IntPtr)handler, x, y);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // for content of combo full load
                Console.WriteLine("Putting keystrokes");
                for (int i = 0; i < (keystrokesCount < 2 ? keystrokesCount+1 : keystrokesCount+2); i++)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
                }
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                HideBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_BOTTOM);

                Console.WriteLine("Keys down pressed, {0} would be choosen", (SYMBOLS)keystrokesCount);
                //Console.WriteLine("From library: Sent {0} strokes, error: {1}", strokesPut, lastErr);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();

                ShowBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_TOPMOST);
                PutSingleClick((IntPtr)handler, x, y);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                for (int i = 0; i < keystrokesCount+5; i++)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}");
                }
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                HideBrowser((IntPtr)handler, HWND_BOTTOM);

                Console.WriteLine("Keys up pressed, ALL would be choosen");
                //Console.WriteLine("From library: Sent {0} strokes, error: {1}", strokesPut, lastErr);
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void ShowBrowser(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr precHwnd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Showing browser...");
            ShowWindow(GetParent(hwnd), SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            SetWindowPos(GetParent(hwnd), precHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }

        private static void HideBrowser(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr precHwnd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hiding browser...");
            SetWindowPos(GetParent(hwnd), precHwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            ShowWindow(GetParent(hwnd), SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I already have it, tested it a behaves the same as described above. Whole code will be in few minutes as edit. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I can't understand why you wouldn't use automation. And I don't understand why you would use SendInput in a native DLL when there is .net SendKeys. But, as I said, automation is where to start.

Comment: Ad automation - If it can be simply substituted (esp. keystrokes), can you provide me part of code how to use it? Ad SendKeys - it is my first project of that kind (normally I'm working on applications without, or very simplified GUI), early I worked with winapi, about WPF, WForms or similar I had no awareness, and now I remember about WAPI and native C libs :) But, your suggestion via SendKeys (.SendWait, because .Send throws InvalidOperationException as it unsupporded in console or WPF) the problem resists. On my machine works well, but on others (two independent) is not. RemakedC#codeInEdit

Comment: No, I'm not really interested in this. I don't want to write the code for you. If you don't want to do basic research, that gives me no enthusiasm to help. Sorry.

Comment: OK, I'll try to rewrite it using an automation :) and I'm not want to write code for me by yourself, only if you have some example (part of older project, whatever), where I can start. No more :) Thanks for your help

Comment: There are many many examples online for automation.